# Autofac Multi Tenant override and IEnumerable<T> inject/resolve

Tags: autofac, multi-tenant

Please forgive my non-native English:

In short, What is the best way for a tenant to override default `IEnumerable<T>` registration?

TL;DR So I have a service `ServiceToBeResove(IEnumerable<IShitty> svcs)` need an `IEnumerable<IShitty>` dependency, but we found not all our tenants have services registered as `IShitty`, so in our application container we create an not implemented `NoImplementShitty` and register it as a TypeService of `IShitty` to server as a default one to make resolve process happy, we do get tenant-specific if tenant have registration and this default non-implemented if tenant forgot to register. But we soon find the `ServiceToBeResove` will have both tenants implemented registered `IShitty` and the default `NoImplementShitty` for its dependence of IEnumerable. What I really want for the `IEnumerable<IShitty>` dependency is just used tenant registered (registered 1 or more), if tenant not registered, just use the default `NoImplementShitty` as the `IEnumerable<IShitty>`. I have played with `.OnlyIf()`, `OnlyIfRegistered()`, `.PreventDefault()` on the app container and it really not helps since autofac will build default first and then tenant. I can certainly use the `NoImplementShitty` for all the tenant that missing registration of `IShitty` but it doesn't seem to take the advantage of multiple tenant's override-default features.

To be more specific, In our base `AgreementModule`, we have

```
builder.RegisterType<NoOpAgreementHandler>() //NoOpAgreementHandler is the IShitty
    .As<IAgreementHandler>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

In our tenantA, we have

```
public class TenantAContainerBuilder : ITenantContainerBuilder
{
    public virtual object TenantId => "1";
    public virtual void Build(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<TenantAAgreementHandler>()
            .As<IAgreementHandler>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

We build container as below:

```
var appContainer = builder.Build();
var tenantIdentifier = new ManualTenantIdentificationStrategy(); //We have our own strategy here I just use the ManualTenantIdentificationStrategy for example
var multiTenantContainer = new MultitenantContainer(tenantIdentifier, appContainer);
//GetTenantContainerBuilders will basically give you all TenantBuilder like TenantAContainerBuilder above
foreach (IGrouping<object, ITenantContainerBuilder> source in GetTenantContainerBuilders().GroupBy(x => x.TenantId))
{
    var configurationActionBuilder = new ConfigurationActionBuilder();
    configurationActionBuilder.AddRange(source.Select(x => new Action<ContainerBuilder>(x.Build)));
    multiTenantContainer.ConfigureTenant(source.Key, configurationActionBuilder.Build());
}
```

When try to resolving the service, if we do:

```
public DisbursementAgreementManager(IEnumerable<IAgreementHandler> agreementHandlers)
{
    _agreementHandlers = agreementHandlers;
}
```

The agreementHandlers will be an IEnumerable of `NoOpAgreementHandler` and `TenantAAgreementHandler`, seems wierd to have `NoOpAgreementHandler` and I thought we will only get `TenantAAgreementHandler`. But if we change the DisbursementAgreementManager to

```
public DisbursementAgreementManager(IAgreementHandler agreementHandler)
{
    _agreementHandler = agreementHandler;
}
```

We will get only the `TenantAAgreementHandler` which is expected.

Comment: How do you implement multi-tenants ? How do you register your `IShitty` implementations ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Sorry for the late reply, I added the detailed implementations above, please let me know if you are confused and what else you may need?

Comment: The dynamic selection of the implementation involved here seems to involve logic that is outside the purpose of dependency injection. In general, if you're resolving a collection of implementations, getting an empty collection is perfectly justified: either all are run, or nothing if empty. A no-op in this case is redundant. This question has an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) feel to it, so let me ask: *why* does `DisbursementAgreementManager` *need* registrations to resolve in this way from the container?

Comment: @MarcL. The reason we add the no-op is we have unit tests for registration/resolve in order to make sure all registration is properly configured. The reason why `DisbursementAgreementManager` need `IEnumerable<IAgreementHandler> agreementHandlers` is because it may generate multiple agreements and each is done differently.

Comment: Is there logic internal to `DisbusementAgreementManager` logic (external to `IAgreementHandler`) that determines how or which `IAgreementHandler` is run? Or is all the logic self-contained to `IAgreementHandler` and they are just all allowed to run themselves?

Comment: @MarcL.The logic is self-contained inside each `IAgreementHandler `. If we specify internal logic for choosing which handler to run inside `DisbusementAgreementManager`, I feel we are not taking advantage of IoC

Comment: You're already taking advantage of IoC, but the question is whether you're asking more of it than is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of Autofac is there for a reason. Asking it to do it differently would be adding application logic at the dependency-injection level, which violates the separation of concerns (DI should only inject dependencies) and leads directly to surprising behavior ("Why did DI not inject every available component?") and undercuts the maintainability of the system.

This may be a non-issue.

> The logic is self-contained inside each `IAgreementHandler`.

If so, at the point where they are invoked by `DisbursementAgreementManager`, they are all called and then perform their own logic (which may include a decision whether to do anything all). E.g.:

```
foreach (var ah in _agreementHandlers) ah.Agree(disbursementInfo);
```

or maybe something like

```
foreach (var ah in _agreementHandlers.Where(a => a.ShouldRun(data) || overridingCondition)) 
{
    var agreement = ah.Agree(info);
    this.Process(agreement);
}
```

or whatever. The point is that if `NoOpAgreementHandler` is doing what it is supposed to (that is, nothing) then it should have no effect when it is called. No problem.

If the situation is other than described, then `NoOpAgreementHandler` and possibly `IAgreementHandler` need to be refactored.

---

There is another point of concern:

> The reason we add the no-op is we have unit tests for registration/resolve in order to make sure all registration is properly configured.

Your testing requirements are bleeding into your primary logic. These DI configuration tests should be independent of the production DI configuration. `NoOpAgreementHandler` shouldn't even be in your primary project, just a member of the unit test project.

Comment: Thank you. But if I isolate `NoOpAgreementHandler` in the unit test, how do I know if I am missing some registration for `IAgreementHandler` before runtime?

Or more appropriately, what is a good pattern for the unit test to make sure all services are properly registered for the unit test before deployed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. How does `NoOpAgreementHandler` help you test registrations of other components?